# Android Service CPU Consumption

Tags: android

Recently I have been helping my professor to develop an Android app, which is related to speech processing. Therefore this app involves lots of real-time computation including FFT and inverse-FFT. When the app runs in the foreground, it works okay. However when the app runs in Service, the app will become unresponsive.

Does anyone know the reason? Is it because when app is running in Service, its CPU consumption is limited? Can anyone give me some solutions? I am a newb in Android Programming...Thank you very much

Comment: i dont know if you write your code correctly or not if you didnt show any code

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I believe the code is correct because the app can run in the foreground quite robustly. The only problem is when it runs in Service. When in Service, no error occurs and no exception is thrown. The app just runs for a short while then becomes unresponsive and frozen.  The reason why I do not show the code because it is very long like several thousands lines of code.

Comment: are you using get method from your service in your main UI?

Comment: @philPolyU You are going to have to describe how you have setup your code in the Service.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a CPU wakelock to the service.  More information on wakelocks can be found at https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html